# How to use Sqldelight with Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, sqldelight

There are apparently Kotlin coroutines extension functions for SqlDelight, but I don't know how to implement them since I can't find documentation.

I have a normal query that looks like this:

```
val allItems
  get() = itemQueries.selectAll().mapToList()
```

Can I turn this into a suspend function?

Answer (score 10):

There is currently (v1.2.1) no suspend function support for SqlDelight queries, however you can consume a Coroutines Flow object, which is even better. To do this you need to add the coroutines extension library in your app gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:1.2.1"
}
```

Then turn your query into this:

```
val allItems: Flow<List<Item>> = 
  itemQueries.selectAll()
    .asFlow()
    .mapToList()
```

This flow emits the query result, and emits a new result every time the database changes for that query.

You can then `.collect{}` the results inside a coroutine scope.

Comment: Addition to this excellent answer for multiplatform projects:
add dependency in commonMain and use latest lib version (which is 1.3.0 currently)
`commonMain.dependencies { implementation ....}`

Comment: Official documentation: https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/multiplatform_sqlite/coroutines/

Comment: Without suspend function support, doesn't it mean that all queries are blocking? It seems the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65988279/1729795) is the good one.

Comment: What is the exact package of `asFlow()` extension method?

Answer (score 6):

For single-shot queries, you don't need the coroutine extension library. Instead, just do:

```
suspend fun getAllItems() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    itemQueries.selectAll().mapToList()
}
```

The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359884/444761) answer is specific to when you want to react to changes in the database.